# Codeigniter Rest Server - Fatal error: Class 'CI_Exceptions' not found

Tags: php, codeigniter, fatal-error, codeigniter-restserver

I try to create a rest API for my android app using CodeIgniter rest services. Everything is fine on localhost. but when I upload it on live server and test again it throws the error. I creating rest API very first time so I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.
It still works fine on localhost.
Please help me to find out where I make mistake or it is a live server problem.
Your answers will be appreciated. Thanks
[image]

Comment: what are your PHP version in localhost and live server?

Comment: On localhost the PHP version is 7.1.8 and on server my php version is 5.4.45

Comment: may be some files hasnt uploaded to the server .check is there clexception class in correct folder ?

Comment: @AbdulAhmadMatin Should I upgrade my php version on live server.

Comment: @FastSnail The CI_Exceptions class is inside system/core folder

Comment: if you have control to cpanel of server yes you can upgrade PHP version

Comment: @AbdulAhmadMatin Yes I have control of cpanel. but I want to ask if I upgrade it to latest version. Can this upgrade of php version cause errors in my other live projects?. and I give it a try to find out if it is a php version error by using different php versions on localhost.

Comment: maybe create a problem for other projects.

Comment: @AbdulAhmadMatin I just tested this on php version 5.6.37 on localhost. It works fine why?. Okay anyway thank you for your valuable time.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to give answer of my question. I hope this will help others to solve this type of error. **I changed my PHP version on server of a particular domain from 5.4.45 to 7.1.8**. Before I changing my PHP version it gives me error **CI_Exceptions class not found**. and then I changed my PHP version and now that's working for me.
I faced some other problems also but I solved them by help of stackoverflow
I hope this will help others