# CodeIgniter Message: "Class not found" on live server

Tags: linux, windows, codeigniter, class, exception

After pushing our local CodeIgniter environment (Windows) to a test server (Linux) we've ran into the following Exception:

```
An uncaught Exception was encountered
 Type: Error
 Message: Class 'ManagementStatus' not found
 Filename: ../LO_MaintenanceItem.php
 Line Number: 300
 Backtrace:
 File: ../LO_MaintenanceItem.php
 Line: 34
. . .
```

In this case 'ManagementStatus' is a model that extends LODatamapper, as defined here:

```
class ManagementStatus extends LODataMapper
{
    . . . .
}
```

In turn, LODataMapper is a class that extends DataMapper, as defined here:

```
abstract class LODataMapper extends DataMapper
{    . . .
```

**What we've tried**

- Turning it off- and on-again
- Checked for existence of class file
- Check for capitalization of file names [(as suggested here)](https://forum.codeigniter.com/thread-75621.html)
- Compared PHP versions of local / testing [(as suggested here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51914135/codeigniter-rest-server-fatal-error-class-ci-exceptions-not-found)

*Any idea what else we might try / what might be going on?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the capitalization on your models. This is most likely your issue.
Only the first letter in the filename can be a capital.